# How can I display current Timezone offset in GMT, in Elm

Tags: date, time, offset, elm

> I'm stuck on getting the current Timezone offset from the Date in Elm.
>
> ```
> Date.now
> ```
>
> This returns
>   `<Thu Feb 22 2018 20:42:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)>` as string
>   As I have explored in Elm's core lib of date and time, and they don't provide any direct method to fetch the current timezone offset. So what should I do?

```
import Html as App
import Html exposing (..)
import Date exposing (Date)
import Task


type alias Model = 
  Maybe Date


type Msg = 
  SetDate (Maybe Date)


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update (SetDate date) _ = 
  (date, Cmd.none)


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div [] [ text <| dateString model ]


dateString : Model -> String
dateString model =
  case model of
    Nothing -> "No date here"
    Just date ->
      (toString <| date)

now : Cmd Msg
now = 
  Task.perform (Just >> SetDate) Date.now




main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
  App.program 
    { init = ( Nothing, now ) 
    , view = view
    , subscriptions = always Sub.none 
    , update = update
    }
```

> I need this `+0530` as in the float `5.5`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elm's DateTime functions are pretty sparse at the moment, but justinmimbs Date.Extra library is my go to for this type of problem. Check it out [here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/justinmimbs/elm-date-extra/latest/Date-Extra)

You can import it as such,

```
import Date.Extra exposing (offsetFromUtc)
```

And, then where you had `toString <| date` change your pipeline to

```
date
    |> offsetFromUtc
    |> toString
```

That'll give you your offset in minutes, if you want the float value, just divide the int by 60. Simple function here to do so:

```
divBy60 : Int -> Float
divBy60 t =
    toFloat t / 60.0
```

then just change your pipeline again to

```
date
    |> offsetFromUtc
    |> divBy60
    |> toString
```

Comment: let me give it a try.